# How to Union multiple DStreams Dynamically..?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am Trying to join multiple Dstreams (Which are created from subscribing multiple topics from Kafka) Dynamically.I am not able to hold all combined streams data,Can any one help me to join multiple Dstream.

In my bellow code I am looping over topics and Constructing Dstreams, with this I am able to combine only two Dstreams.
I don't know how to create empty Dstream, I think if we create empty Dstream we can achieve this.

Bellow is my code:

```
var i:Int=0
var JoinedStream:DStream[ConsumerRecord[String,String]]=null;

var firstStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](streamingContext, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](Array(topicNameONe(0).asInstanceOf[JsString].value), kafkaParams))

for(i <- 0 to topicNameONe.length-1 )
  {
    JoinedStream=firstStream.union(KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](streamingContext, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](Array(topicNameONe(i).asInstanceOf[JsString].value), kafkaParams)))
  }`
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to union anything. You can subscribe to multiple topics at once:

```
val topics: Array[String] = ???

KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, 
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
```